# Bind object property from dropdown to different object property

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-datatables

I am trying to bind a the selected option from a dropdown to a specific object property that lives within a data-table. Please code below.

```
<data-table-column [property]="'CostTypeId'"
                   [header]="'Type'"
                   [sortable]="false"
                   [resizable]="true">
    <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1"
                [(ngModel)]="item.CostTypeId"
                [class.is-invalid]="validateCostType(item)">
            <option *ngFor="let type of recoveryCostTypes" [(ngValue)]="type.Id">{{type.Description}}</option>
        </select>
    </ng-template>
</data-table-column>
```

but I am not able to get the value through. I keeps saying the item.CostTypeId property is undefined. Am I perhaps binding incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Have a different `ngModel` property lets say 'modelValue' and when the dropdown value changes `dropdownChange()` function is called, assign the dropdown value to the selectedRow of the datatable.

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1"
                [(ngModel)]="modelValue" (change)="dropdownChange(modelValue)"
                [class.is-invalid]="validateCostType(item)">
            <option *ngFor="let type of recoveryCostTypes" [(ngValue)]="type.Id"> 
            {{type.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

In .ts file

```
modelValue: string;
selectedRow = {};

dropdownChange(value){
  selectedRow.CostTypeId = value;
}
```